# CMake: How to differentiate between library files and unit tests for this library?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, static-libraries

I have created a C++ library `MyLib` with the following structure:

```
MyLib/
  |-- Module1/
       |-- SubModule1/
             |-- Tests/
                  |-- .cpp files (unit tests)
             |-- .cpp files (library sources)
       |-- Tests/
             |-- .cpp files (unit tests)
       |-- .cpp files (library sources)
  |-- Module2/
       |-- Tests/
             |-- .cpp files (unit tests)
       |-- .cpp files (library sources)
  |-- ...
  |-- CMakeLists.txt
```

In words, the source files of the library are distributed in many directories and subdirectories. Each directory may contain a directory `Tests`, which contains unit tests for the modules in the parent directory.

I am using CMake v2.8 to build the library (`MyLib.a`) and unit tests for this library (an executable file named `MyLibTests`). These are the relevant rules I use to achieve this:

```
# Build MyLib.
file(GLOB_RECURSE MyLib_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} *.cpp)
# Filter out source files of unit tests.
foreach(ITEM ${MyLib_SOURCES})
    if(${ITEM} MATCHES Tests/*)
        list(REMOVE_ITEM MyLib_SOURCES ${ITEM})
    endif()
endforeach()
add_library(MyLib STATIC ${MyLib_SOURCES})

# Build MyLibTests.
file(GLOB_RECURSE MyLib_TESTS_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} *.cpp)
# Filter out non-unit-tests source files.
foreach(ITEM ${MyLib_TESTS_SOURCES})
    if(NOT ${ITEM} MATCHES Tests/*)
        list(REMOVE_ITEM MyLib_TESTS_SOURCES ${ITEM})
    endif()
endforeach()
add_executable(MyLibTests ${MyLib_TESTS_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(MyLibTests MyLib ${UNIT_TESTS_FRAMEWORK_LIBS})
```

Is there a better way of finding which `.cpp` files form the library and which `.cpp` files are unit tests for this library? I was not able to come up with a proper expression for `file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)` that would do it.

Comment: First off the developers of CMake recommend not using GLOB for source files because adding new files will not force cmake to run. Second if you want to continue doing that can't you move the source files to a src folder and so the Tests folder will not be inside the tree GLOB searches?

Comment: @drescherjm First: I have set up my project to automatically run cmake before make. Therefore, adding or removing files is not an issue. Second: I can, but I would rather stay with the described structure.

Comment: Then you will probably have to use to your current approach. Although you may want to make this a macro.